# An alternative find file function with the same default folder, every time

Tags: emacs, editor, elisp

I'd like to bind super and 9 to open the "find file:", "C-x C-f" menu with ~/x/ as the "default path" in the user input field, no matter what directory the file I currently have open is in. My elisp skills are unfortunately pretty basic. I would really appreciate some help with this.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-9") 'enter_find_file_with_dir_x_as_default)

(defun enter_find_file_with_dir_x_as_default ()
"Enter find file with the path ~/x/ as the default input every time."
())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a command that calls  `read-file-name` with the directory you want as the default (in the `interactive` spec), and then calls `find-file` on the file name read.

```
(defun my-find-file (file)
  "..."
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "File: " "~/x/")))
  (find-file file))
```

See the doc for `read-file-name`, to decide what other arguments you might want (e.g., whether you accept only existing file names or allow a new-file buffer).

Note too that if you want to bind this to a key then it has to be a command, so it needs an `interactive` spec.  If you just wanted a function that reads a file name starting in directory `~/x/` then the answer is `read-file-name` -- just pass it `~/x/` as its `DIR` argument.

See the Elisp manual, node `Reading File Names`, for more information. (`C-h i`; choose `Elisp`; `i read-file-name`.)